# The non-negativity condition of a discretized mean-reverting Heston model with stochastic violatilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, heston

I happened to encounter the following discretized mean-reverting Heston model with stochastic volatilities in a paper
$$
P(t) = P(t-1) + v_1(u_1-P(t-1))+\sqrt{\sigma(t)}\cdot \epsilon_1(t) \\
\sigma(t) = \sigma(t-1) + v_2(u_2-\sigma(t-1))+\sqrt{\sigma(t-1)}\cdot \epsilon_2(t)
$$
where $v_1=v_2=0.1,u_1=100,u_2=0.01$ are pre-set parameters, and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \sim N(0,1)$ follow the normal distribution IID. Recall that in the original Heston Model formulation, there is a condition (known as the Feller condition) to make sure that the values under the square root is positive. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model#cite_note-Albr2007-3) for more info. But in this case, how can I ensure that the value of $\sigma$ to be positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous version of your equation for $\sigma(t)$ reads
$$
d\sigma(t)=v_2(u_2-\sigma(t))\,dt+\sqrt{\sigma(t)}\,dW^\sigma_t\,.
$$
In this notation, the [Feller condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model#Basic_Heston_model) ensuring $\sigma(t)>0$ is $2v_2u_2>1\,.$ This is **not** the case for the values $v_2=0.1,u_2=0.01$ you have chosen. Note that the Heston model also has a vol-of-vol parameter $\xi$:
$$
d\sigma(t)=v_2(u_2-\sigma(t))\,dt+\xi\sqrt{\sigma(t)}\,dW^\sigma_t\,
$$
and that the Feller conditon in full glory says $2v_2u_2>\xi^2\,.$ In other words, you should use that vol-of-vol $\xi$ and not make it as large as $\xi=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't realize that. Is this exactly the [Euler's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method)? So for instance if I define $\zeta = 2v_2u_2 = 0.002$, will the Feller condition follow from the continuous case?

Comment: Your discretization method is Euler's method (fully explicit). I think that it is hard to figure out a Feller condition for the discrete case. Better than getting theoretical headaches is to test what your discretization is producing.

Comment: Agree. Now I have some ideas to test and to modify the model. Thank you!